List itemindent not working within the list environment while using \DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}}
I have tried to create a list item using the \itemindent command, but it does not work within the list, when I am using \DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}}. I also need to ensure accessibility. Below is my Minimal Working Example (MWE):
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table}}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\def\openendlist{\begingroup%
\list{}{%
\topsep=0pt\parsep=0pt%
\partopsep=0pt\itemsep=0pt\labelsep=0pt%
\labelwidth=0pt\leftmargin=11.5pt\itemindent=-\leftmargin%
%
\usecounter{enumi}}%
}

\def\myendlist{\endlist\endgroup}

\section*{References}

\openendlist

\item Aakko, M., \& Koskennurmi-Sivonen, R. (2013). Designing sustainable fashion: Possibilities and challenges. \textit{Research Journal of Textile and Apparel}, \textit{17}(1), 13--22. \href{https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1108/RJTA-17-01-2013-B002}{https://doi.org/10.1108/RJTA-17-01-2013-B002}

\item Adger, W. N., \& Jordan, A.. (2009). Sustainability: Exploring the process and outcomes of governance. In W. N. Adger \& A. Jordan (Eds.), \textit{Governing sustainability} (pp. 3--32). Cambridge University Press.

\item Aminpour, P., Gray, S., Richardson, R., Singer, A., Castro-Diaz, L., Schaefer, M., Ramlan, M. A., \& Chikowore, N. R. (2019). Perspectives of scholars on the nature of sustainability: A survey study. \textit{International Journal of Sustainability in Higher Education}, \textit{21}(1), 34--53. \href{https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1108/IJSHE-05-2019-0161/full/html}{https://doi.org/10.1108/IJSHE-05-2019-0161/full/html}


\myendlist

\end{document}

Output without using \DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}}

Output with using \DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}}


This has been corrected in the dev version. So use pdflatex-dev or lualatex-dev.

@UlrikeFischer, I compiled it using lualatex-dev.exe (2023)

well we have 2024. A current latex-dev uses LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> pre-release-2.

@UlrikeFischer, Thanks for the updates.

As mentioned in the comments, this is fixed with a current format. Your example produces

